# SVG: How to remove space between two tspan tags?

Tags: svg

How to remove white space between `tspan` tags and get `REDGREENBLUE` instead of `RED GREEN BLUE` ?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="1128" height="191" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="80">
    <tspan fill="red">RED</tspan>
    <tspan fill="green">GREEN</tspan>
    <tspan fill="blue">BLUE</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Put tspans one next to each other

Comment: @enxaneta Indeed, that worked, Thanks! I need to disable my "auto format on save" in VSCode...

Comment: Another solution is to add something like `dx="-18"` in the `tspan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give font-size zero to the parent `text` element. and give desired font size to the child elements

```css
text {
  font-size: 0px;
}

tspan {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1128" height="191" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="80">
    <tspan fill="red">red</tspan>
    <tspan fill="green">green</tspan>
    <tspan fill="blue">blue</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This may not work in all browsers. According to the CSS spec, a `font-size` specified with a length must have a _positive_ length value.